# App crashing on first use of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use a UIImagePickerController in my app and am getting a crash after being prompted for access to the photo album for the first time. Here is the crash error:

**[PUUIAlbumListViewController requiresAuth]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd6a18b0**

I can't find any references to this error anywhere. Anyone have any clues? Thanks!

```
-(void)showPicker
{    
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];


    self.imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];    
}




*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PUUIAlbumListViewController requiresAuth]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd1587d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03bcb5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0394e8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03c68903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x03bbb90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x03bbb4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MyApp Mobile                      0x000042e8 -[MyAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 2989
    6   UIKit                               0x027afef4 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 329
    7   UIKit                               0x027b5afb _alertItemStateChanged + 81
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x03c27733 __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke + 163
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x03c27524 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    10  CoreFoundation                       0x03c277fd ____CFXNotificationPostToken_block_invoke + 173
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x03b8a1c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x03b533f9 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 361
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x03b71843 __CFRunLoopRun + 2355
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x03b70ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x03b708db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0477f9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0477f809 GSEventRun + 104
    18  UIKit                               0x027b6d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    19  MyApp                      0x00166361 main + 264
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0431e725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Based on the limited information here, you are calling a selector that doesn't exist on an instance, or the instance no longer exists. Did you double check you haven't deallocated the instance before the selector is fired?

Comment: Some code and a stack trace would help in diagnosing your crash.

Comment: Sorry, I should know better...one sec.

Comment: How do you declare `imagePicker`? I suspect it may be of a wrong type.

Comment: @BlackRider not related to imagePicker. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the crash wasn't related to UIImagePickerController directly, but was occurring in the appdelegate on applicationDidBecomeActive when calling a selector on self.navigationController.visibleViewController without checking to see if the visibileViewController responded to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere your code is looking for a method: requiresAuth in your class: PUUIAlbumListViewController.  It's not there. Code the missing method or remove the call to it.